# Related to importing WebDriver and FirefoxDriver in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I have added latest Selenium Java 3.7.1 version jar files in my code and while importing WebDriver and FirefoxDriver, I am facing issue. Please find screenshots for the same.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the directory of Firefox binary and gecko driver to PATH variable,if so just open cmd type in geckodriver it shouldn’t return an error! If the directory locations are added in the path,I think it should work